# Can I use google groups to control who can access my Google AppMaker application?

Tags: google-app-maker

My application needs to be restricted to 4 groups of users (35 users in total) where members are maintained through google groups. Can I leverage on that collective address to specify access to my AppMaker application?

[Click here to view screen capture of my deployment settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h64wR.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you absolutely can do this. Even more, you can create multiple roles for different user groups and make your app behave differently for each of them. You can learn more about securing your deployments here:

[Secure Deployments](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/security/secure-your-app#secure_deployments)

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for this. I'll try to do some tests again using groups addresses.